# Is it possible using c++ library function in c prog?

Tags: c++, c

In c program, I want run c++ library function(s), but I don't know how can I do that. Like ever c++ programmer, I know how to use c program under c++ prog. therefore, I wonder it is possible using c++ library function, namely cout, vector etc., in c ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, you cannot use C++ facilities in C.

However, a C++ library may choose to export some of its functionality to C programs, by declaring them `extern "C"`. If your C++ library doesn't do this, you will have to write some wrappers (in C++) that do this.

Note that such exported functionality have to conform to C's limitations. For example, you can't use non-POD types, function overloading, operator overloading, conversion operators, RTTI, exceptions, templates, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As Chris Jester-Young said, you can't use them directly. But you can write wrappers in C++ that export the functionality as plain c functions.

Basically you write a Create-Method (e.g. CreateVector) that returns a handle (e.g. the this pointer as int), a Destroy-Method (e.g. DestroyVector) that takes the handle and deletes the object. Then you have to wrap each member method of the object. The wrapper method has the same signature, except that it takes an additional argument - the handle.

This is - depending on the amount of methods to wrap - a lot of repetitive work. But it is easy work. For an example of "object oriented programming in C using handles", just take a look at the Windows-API.

Answer (score 0):

You must create `extern "C"` wrapper functions around the C++ functions you want to use. This step requires you to manually choose names for the functionality you want.

```
//Header file:

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int *find_int( int *first, int *last, int value );

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

//C++ source file:

int *find_int( int *first, int *last, int value ) {
    return std::find( first, last, value );
}
```

Compile this into a library (static or dynamic) or just put it alongside the C source code in the project, depending how your build environment works.

Comment: std::find would probably work, but there are no guarantees that the C++ runtime is properly initialized if used in a program with a C main() function.

Comment: @Bo: True that. In particular, iostreams won't work. Of course, it may be easy to simply put `main` in a C++ file.